# siebel compile using vba macros?

Tags: excel, siebel, vba

We got one assignment to compile selected siebel objects using VBA macros.
When i say selected it means list of objects will be available in one excel sheet.

is it possible to compile automatically in VBA?

any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with this.

**NO.**

You can double check with Oracle support.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ranjith already mentioned, there is no supported API to compile an SRF. This applies to both the VBA COM and the Java Bean.

Even if you managed to find an undocumented way of compiling the SRF using VBA, it would be unsupported by Oracle. Any issue you have afterwards they will request you reproduce your issue with a standard compile. So, I'd also recommend not investing in this route.

For arguments sake I'll assume that there is a supported way for a moment. Even then I'd argue that Excel is the worst way to automate a compile and deployment of a SRF. It's a client application, it can't - or is difficult - to run on a command line and doesn't interface with proper Continuous Integration tools like Jenkins, Travis CI, Bamboo and [the lot](https://xebialabs.com/periodic-table-of-devops-tools/).

Building a CI/CD pipeline for Siebel from scratch is complex. Take your time to research the matter. Have a look at the commercial party support and if you do want to develop your own, find a good DevOps engineer and couple him with a strong Siebel Engineer with deployment experience.

Answer (score 0):

As all previous commentators mentioned, this is a challenge, but still possible.
Matter the fact you can use scripting on the **Siebel Tools Object Compiler** service, which is triggered via **siebdev.exe** batch compile call. Messing around *RepositoryName* input parameter can give you the way to pass Excel file name into the service.
Incremental compilation could be performed, following these complex steps on the PreInvokeMethod hook:

- Open a transaction, using **EAI Transaction Service** (may require some ddl libraries from the Windows Siebel Server distribution)
- Create a new project (e.g. "__my_incremental_compilation__")
- Find the desired repository objects and move them to your project
- Pass project name to the **ProjectsList** parameter of the service's Inputs property set
- Continue service call (wait for the end of the compilation)
- Rollback the transaction

This worked well for me, when I got stuck with the same question.

Hope it helps you!